# Strong maximum principle in entire space

Tags: elliptic-pde, maximum-principle

Let $n\geq 3$, $K$ is a bounded function in $\mathbb{R}^n$. If $u$ is a nonegative solution but not equal to 0 of $$-\Delta u=Ku^{\frac{n+2}{n-2}}\quad \text{in }\,\mathbb{R}^n.$$
Can we use the strong maximum principle to deduce $u$ is positive in $\mathbb{R}^n$? I saw the strong maximum principle in the bounded domain, what about the entire space like $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Isn't u=0 a nonnegative solution?

Comment: sorry, here $u$ not equal to 0.

Comment: Yes, the usual proof for subharmonic/superharmonic functions works in any open connected set and gives $u=0$ if u vanishes somewhere. Or else you can use the strong minimun principle in any ball.

Comment: Can you give some details about the proof, thanks.

Comment: I just use that a superharmonic function with a global miniminum is constant in a open connected set. No boundedness assumption on the set is needed. So, if your u is zero somewhere, since it is nonegative, it has a minimum and it is zero everywhere.

Comment: I'm wondering if we do not need the sign condition of $K(x)$?

Comment: Please quote my name so I receive a notification, I saw your reply by chance. Sorry, I just realized that K is not a positive constant!

Comment: Sorry, I just don't know how to quote your name, may be @ 
Giorgio Metafune like this? And I guess this may not need the sign condition of $K$ by write $K=K^{+}+K^{-}$.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune how to guarantee that $(1+K u^{\frac{4}{n-2}}) \geq 0$ in $B\left(x_0, r\right)$? since $K$ may be always negative.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $u$ is strictly positive. Assume that $F=\{x:u(x)=0\}$ is non-empty. $F$ is clearly closed and I show that is open. Let $x_0 \in F$ and $r>0$ such that $u-\Delta u=u(1+Ku^{\frac{4}{n-2}}) \geq 0$ in $B(x_0,r)$. Such $r$ exists since $K$ is bounded. Applying the strong minimum principle in $B(x_0,r)$ to the operator $I-\Delta$, we see that $u\equiv 0$ in $B(x_0,r)$.

Comment: how to guarantee that $(1+K u^{\frac{4}{n-2}}) \geq 0$ in $B\left(x_0, r\right)$? since $K$ may be always negative.

Comment: Just use that $u(x) \to 0$ as $x \to x_0$.